# Adding an endpoint behavior extension through code

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF web service, self hosted, configured through the configuration file.

I want to add an endpoint behavior extension to one of my endpoint behaviors programmatically. Adding it through the configuration file is very easy.

```
<extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="EnableCors" type="CorsEnablingExtension.EnableCorsSupportBehaviorElement, CorsEnablingExtension"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>

<behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SoapBehavior"/>
        <behavior name="RestBehavior">
          <CustomBehavior/>
          <EnableCors/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

So I can just throw EnableCors in there and everything's fine. But I want to add a delegate parameter in the behavior constructor so I'd like to add it through code, but keep all the other configuration elements.

If I add a static Configure method in my service implementation

```
public static void Configure(ServiceConfiguration config)
```

then I have to do all of the configuration programmatically which is too much hassle.

So the question is, can I add that `IEndpointBehavior` programmatically and keep the rest of the configuration in the config file ?

Comment: How are you running your service? Do you have a custom `ServiceHost`? Or use the default IIS-stuff

Comment: If it's self-hosted, I doubt it's hosted by IIS. :)

Comment: Calling config.LoadFromConfiguration() inside Configure does seem to do what I want.